# Many tomcat process started by IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

On some days I start/stop a tomcat form Intellij tens of times. Once in a while, restarting a Run Configuration, I get a JVM_Bind error stating that port 8080 is already in use. In Windows, I open the Task Manager  to kill the tomcat Java process and then I see not one but 3 or 5 or 9 Java processes running. With processexp I see all of them have been started with teh  command line from the IntelliJ Run Configuration.

I wonder what is going on. What are all these tomcat processes that do not use port 8080? Why is shutting doen the server failing once in a while?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: 11.1.5 Ultimate Edition

Comment: I was having a similar issue with the EAP (Early Access Preview) edition and after a frustrating couple of hours discovered that I had multiple java.exe files in my Windows registry. I cleaned Java from my computer, did a clean install in a directory without any spaces or special characters, then set my environment variables. I do not believe that is the exact answer to your question but it could be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. Few days ago (end of the month) I left the project I was experiencing this problem and now I do not have access to the particular machine, so I can't try this now. I'll try it the first time I see this happening again.